# Android App Crashing Issue for FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor 3682 >= FD_SETSIZE 1024

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

I am developing an android app using kotlin/jetpack compose and after running the app it crashed about 20 minutes later. The logcat shows the following error. But I can't understand what's the reason.

```
FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor 3682 >= FD_SETSIZE 1024
2023-11-28 19:24:17.444 13050-5258  libc                    com....therapist.android  A  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 5258 (Studio:Socket), pid 13050 (erapist.android)
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/nabu_global/nabu:13/TKQ1.221013.002/V14.0.6.0.TKXMIXM:user/release-keys'
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  Revision: '0'
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  ABI: 'arm64'
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  Timestamp: 2023-11-28 19:24:17.717448799+0600
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  Process uptime: 4875s
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  Cmdline: com.therapist.android
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  pid: 13050, tid: 5258, name: Studio:Socket  >>> com.therapist.android <<<
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  uid: 10249
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  Abort message: 'FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor 3682 >= FD_SETSIZE 1024'
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A      x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000148a  x2  0000000000000006  x3  00000076faf855d0
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A      x4  8080808080808080  x5  8080808080808080  x6  8080808080808080  x7  8080808080808080
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A      x8  00000000000000f0  x9  000000779e683cb0  x10 0000000000000001  x11 000000779e6f87c8
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A      x12 0101010101010101  x13 000000006565ea01  x14 001a39ddfd427000  x15 0000000000000008
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A      x16 000000779e763a80  x17 000000779e73c450  x18 00000076379ee000  x19 00000000000032fa
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A      x20 000000000000148a  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000001  x23 00000076faf86000
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A      x24 00000076faf85960  x25 0000000000000e62  x26 00000076faf858f0  x27 00000076faf85900
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A      x28 00000076faf85968  x29 00000076faf85650
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A      lr  000000779e6e9748  sp  00000076faf855b0  pc  000000779e6e9774  pst 0000000000001000
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A  backtrace:
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A    NOTE: Function names and BuildId information is missing for some frames due
                                                                                                      NOTE: to unreadable libraries. For unwinds of apps, only shared libraries
                                                                                                      NOTE: found under the lib/ directory are readable.
                                                                                                      NOTE: On this device, run setenforce 0 to make the libraries readable.
                                                                                                      NOTE: Unreadable libraries:
                                                                                                      NOTE:   /data/data/com.therapist.android/code_cache/libjvmtiagent_arm64.so
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A        #00 pc 000000000008d774  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168) (BuildId: 449f781894033dce6346794a1ee593e0)
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A        #01 pc 000000000008f5d4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__fortify_fatal(char const*, ...)+128) (BuildId: 449f781894033dce6346794a1ee593e0)
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A        #02 pc 00000000000b8cdc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__FD_SET_chk+128) (BuildId: 449f781894033dce6346794a1ee593e0)
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A        #03 pc 000000000013b29c  /data/data/com.therapist.android/code_cache/libjvmtiagent_arm64.so
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A        #04 pc 0000000000128880  /data/data/com.therapist.android/code_cache/libjvmtiagent_arm64.so
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A        #05 pc 000000000012e580  /data/data/com.therapist.android/code_cache/libjvmtiagent_arm64.so
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A        #06 pc 00000000000f55c8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208) (BuildId: 449f781894033dce6346794a1ee593e0)
2023-11-28 19:24:18.100  5263-5263  DEBUG                   pid-5263                             A        #07 pc 000000000008efbc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+68) (BuildId: 449f781894033dce6346794a1ee593e0)
```

I have used retrofit2 for api calling, I guess the above error occured for the following api calling.

```
 viewModelScope.launch {
            while (isActiveQueueStatus) {
                queueStatusPayload.value?.let {payload->
                    biometricUseCases.fetchQueueStatusData(
                        payload
                    ).onEach {
                        when (it) {
                            is Resource.Error -> {
                                _isQueueStatusLoading.value = false
                                _eventFlow.emit(
                                    UIEvent.ShowSnackBar(
                                        it.message
                                            ?: "Failed to update exercise status! Please try again."
                                    )
                                )
                            }

                            is Resource.Loading -> {
                                _isQueueStatusLoading.value = true
                            }

                            is Resource.Success -> {
                                _isQueueStatusLoading.value = false
                                _queueStatusData.value = it.data
                                _isExerciseLoading.value = false

                                if (it.data?.queue != null) {
                                    processedExerciseList.value = it.data.queue.associateBy { item-> item.exerciseName }
                                }
                                UIEvent.ShowSnackBar(
                                    it.message
                                        ?: "Successfully loaded!"
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }.launchIn(this)
                }

                delay(15000) // 15 seconds
            }
        }
```

**Can anyone please tell me about the above error and how can i handle this?**